# How to do prefix query in Elasticsearch php?

Tags: php, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch

I want to use following JSON query in PHP:

```
{
    "match_phrase" : {
        "message" : {
            "query" : "this is a test",
            "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have PHP code:

```
 $params['body']['query']['match_phrase'] = array(
            "name" => $query
        );

$this->result = $this->client->search($params);
```

How I can convert JSON query in PHP array query according to elasticsearch php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is a like this:

```
$params['body']['query']['match_phrase'] = array(
    "message" => array(
        "query" => $query,
        "analyzer" => "my_analyzer"
    )
);

$this->result = $this->client->search($params);
```

Another way which is probably better when working with Elasticsearch is to use the [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function. That way you can easily write your queries in JSON using the
query DSL without the trouble of constructing it via associative arrays.

```
$json = '{
    "match_phrase" : {
        "message" : {
            "query" : "' . $query . '",
            "analyzer" : "my_analyzer"
        }
    }
}';
$params['body']['query'] = json_decode($json);
$this->result = $this->client->search($params);
```